# Upload files to Owncloud

Tags: owncloud

I wonder, can i upload files to OwnCloud by some post or put request?

My goal - user uploads files to one server1, after submitting form his data
handles and sends to another server2 with Owncloud installed on, then returns
path to file in owncloud back. So record in server1 will have some filename 
property points to owncloud storage.

(Note: I am not talking about WebDAV).

Any other capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

The Own Cloud API exposes an endpoint which makes this possible (both for POST and PUT):

```
post(string  $uri, array  $options = array()) : \OCP\Http\Client\IResponse
```

and

```
put(string  $uri, array  $options = array()) : \OCP\Http\Client\IResponse
```

> Parameters
>
> string    $uri     array  $options Array such as 
>   'body' => [ 'field' =>
>   'abc', 'other_field' => '123', 'file_name' => fopen('/path/to/file',
>   'r'), ], 'headers' => [ 'foo' => 'bar', ], 'cookies' => [' 'foo' =>
>   'bar', ], 'allow_redirects' => [ 'max' => 10, // allow at most 10
>   redirects. 'strict' => true, // use "strict" RFC compliant redirects.
>   'referer' => true, // add a Referer header 'protocols' => ['https'] //
>   only allow https URLs ], 'save_to' => '/path/to/file', // save to a
>   file or a stream 'verify' => true, // bool or string to CA file
>   'debug' => true,

see https://doc.owncloud.org/api/classes/OCP.Http.Client.IClient.html for the relevant section in the API docs

Comment: thanks for u answer, so this endpoints are usual controllers methods?
or i need using them in controller after recieving data via post or put?

Comment: As I use Python to do similar things, I make use of the Python Client Library for Own Cloud:  https://github.com/owncloud/pyocclient. Your use would largely depend on how you are going to do the upload programmatically. I see you exclude WebDAV as an option though, which may limit you to do it without some kind of client application of sorts.

Comment: thanks for u link but i dont understand in python at all, even cant find any file with realization by your link

Comment: I think to further assist I'd need to know how you plan on uploading the file to the server (PHP perhaps?), and if you plan on using the same system to upload to Own Cloud?

Comment: in theory all is very simple

1)In owncloud app controller i get file and it metadata from post or put request

2)using owncloud storage i save metadata in DB and put file then return data with path_to_file

3)access to file just type path in browser

Uploading will be on another server but then sending to my site on owncloud